# SharePoint 2010 open Explorer view in the same window

Tags: 2010, 2007

I have a problem with SharePoint 2010 while we are using it in **IFRAME** html element (in CRM). When user try to open document library in windows explorer ("Open with Explorer" button click) he gets two pop-up windows - one is document library in windows explorer, but another is browser window with error "Navigation to the webpage was canceled". Users are using IE 8 browser in XP Windows (in IE 9 there is no second popup window with error).

My question is - how can we avoid second popup window with error (for IE 8) users ? Or maybe there is a solution to make windows explorer open up in the same window (not pop-uped, like it was in SP 2007)?

Comment: Time to upgrade. I know this doesn't help, but if it works in IE9, you're wasting time and effort fixing something that has been 'fixed'. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for advice :) but then we have to upgrade about hundred PCs. Anyway, maybe there will be the only solution. But the main question here is - can we make window explorer open in the same window (not pop-uped, like it was in SP 2007) ? We have tried this solution: http://www.thesanitypoint.com/archive/2010/10/20/simulating-explorer-view-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx but that does not meet the requirements of exploring folders like in windows explorer.